# Jquery mobil calendary delay

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a jquery mobil calendar.

The calendar list delay 2019-10-29. (image)

[image]

[image]

2019-10-18 the work list is perfect but 2019-10-29, 2019-10-30.....
the work list is delayed.

The javascript is work with Json:

```
[{"name":"Munkaszünet - 24 óra szolgálat","start":"2019-08-23 00:00","end":"2019-08-23 00:00","summary":"Munkaszünet - 24 óra szolgálat"},

{"name":"Munkaszünet - 24 óra szolgálat","start":"2019-10-18 00:00","end":"2019-10-18 00:00","summary":"Munkaszünet - 24 óra szolgálat"}]
```

The javascript:

```
(function($) {
    $.jqmCalendar = function(element, options) {
        var defaults = {
            events : [],
            begin : "start",
            end : "end",
            summary : "name",
            statusz : "statusz",
            icon: "icon", // http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/icons/
            url: "url",
            allDayTimeString: '',
            headerTheme : "b",
            theme : "b",
            dataTheme : "d",
            dividerTheme : "b",
            date : new Date(),
            dateFormatTitle : "yyyy MMMM dd", // http://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat
            dateFormat : "yyyy MMMM dd",
            faszOm : "yyyy-MM-dd",
            version: "1.2.1",
            months : ["Január", "Február", "Március", "Április", "Május", "Június", "Július", "Augusztus", "Szeptember", "Október", "November", "December"],
            days : ["Va", "Hé", "Ke", "Sz", "Cs", "Pé", "Szo"],
            weeksInMonth : 6,
            startOfWeek : 1,
            listItemFormatter : listItemFormatter,
            monthItemsFormatter : monthItemsFormatter,
            transposeTimezone: transposeTimezone
        };
        var plugin = this;
            plugin.settings = null;
        var $element = $(element).addClass("jqm-cal-wrapper"),
            $table,
            $header,
            $tbody,
            $listview,
            $previous,
            $next;

        function init() {
            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            $table = $("<table/>");

            var $thead = $("<thead/>").appendTo($table),
                $tr = $("<tr/>").appendTo($thead),
                $th = $("<th class='ui-bar-" + plugin.settings.headerTheme + " header' colspan='7'/>");

            $previous = $("<a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='arrow-l' data-iconpos='notext' class='previous-btn'>Vissza</a>")
                        .data('date', _skipMonth(plugin.settings.date, -1))
                        .appendTo($th);

            $header = $("<span/>").appendTo($th);

            $next = $("<a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='arrow-r' data-iconpos='notext' class='next-btn'>Előre</a>")
                        .data('date', _skipMonth(plugin.settings.date, 1))
                        .appendTo($th);

            $previous.click(function(event) { 
                            var date = $(this).data('date');
                            refresh(date, true);
                            $next.data('date', _skipMonth(date, 1));
                            $(this).data('date', _skipMonth(date, -1));
                        });

            $next.click(function(event) { 
                            var date = $(this).data('date');
                            refresh(date, true);
                            $previous.data('date', _skipMonth(date, -1));
                            $(this).data('date', _skipMonth(date, 1));
                        });

            $th.appendTo($tr);
            $tr = $("<tr/>").appendTo($thead);
            for ( var i = 0, days = [].concat(plugin.settings.days, plugin.settings.days).splice(plugin.settings.startOfWeek, 7); i < 7; i++ ) {
                $tr.append("<th class='ui-bar-" + plugin.settings.theme + " dayName'>"  + days[i] + "</th>");
            }
            $tbody = $("<tbody/>").appendTo($table);
            $table.appendTo($element);
            $listview = $("<ul data-role='listview' data-theme='" + plugin.settings.dataTheme + "' data-divider-theme='" + plugin.settings.dividerTheme + "' />").insertAfter($table);
            plugin.settings.transposeTimezone(plugin.settings.events);
            refresh(plugin.settings.date, true);    
        }

        function transposeTimezone(events){
            for(var i=0, event; event=plugin.settings.events[i];i++){
                plugin.settings.events[i].start = new Date(plugin.settings.events[i].start.getTime() - plugin.settings.events[i].start.getTimezoneOffset() + (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()*60000);
                plugin.settings.events[i].end = new Date(plugin.settings.events[i].end.getTime() - plugin.settings.events[i].end.getTimezoneOffset() + (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()*60000);
            }
        }

        function _skipMonth(date, month){
            return ( new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+month, 1) );
        }

        function _firstDayOfMonth(date) {
            return ( new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1) ).getDay();
        }

        function _daysBefore(date, fim) {
            var firstDayInMonth = ( fim || _firstDayOfMonth(date) ),
            diff = firstDayInMonth - plugin.settings.startOfWeek;
            return ( diff > 0 ) ? diff : ( 7 + diff );
        }

        function _daysInMonth(date) {
            return ( new Date ( date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0 )).getDate();
        }

        function _daysAfter(date, wim, dim, db) {
            return    (( wim || _weeksInMonth(date) ) * 7 ) - ( dim || _daysInMonth(date) ) - ( db || _daysBefore(date));
        }

        function _weeksInMonth(date, dim, db) {
            return ( plugin.settings.weeksInMonth ) ? plugin.settings.weeksInMonth : Math.ceil( ( ( dim || _daysInMonth(date) ) + ( db || _daysBefore(date)) ) / 7 );
        }

        function addCell($row, date, hidden, selected) {
            var $td = $("<td class='ui-body-" + plugin.settings.theme + "'/>").appendTo($row),
                $a = $("<a href='#' class='ui-btn ui-btn-up-" + plugin.settings.theme + "'/>")
                    .html(date.getDate().toString())
                    .data('date', date)
                    .click(cellClickHandler)
                    .appendTo($td);

                if ( selected ) $a.click();
                if ( hidden ) {
                    $td.addClass("lowres");
                } else {
                    var importance = 0;

                for ( var i = 0, event, 
                begin = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                end = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                event = plugin.settings.events[i]; i++ ) {

                    if ( event[plugin.settings.end].getTime() >= begin.getTime() && event[plugin.settings.begin].getTime() < end.getTime() ) {
                        importance++;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if ( importance > 0 ) {
                    $a.addClass("hasEvent");
                }
                var today = new Date();
                if (date.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() === today.getMonth() && date.getDate() === today.getDate()){
                    $a.addClass("ui-btn-today");
                }
            }
        }

        function cellClickHandler(event) {
            var $this = $(this),
                date = $this.data('date');
            $tbody.find("a.ui-btn-active").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
            $this.addClass("ui-btn-active");

            if ( date.getMonth() !== plugin.settings.date.getMonth() ) {
                refresh(date, false);
                $previous.data('date', _skipMonth(date, -1));
                $next.data('date', _skipMonth(date, 1));
            } else {
                $element.trigger('change', date);
            }
        }

        function refresh(date, userChangedMonth) {
            plugin.settings.date = date = date ||  plugin.settings.date || new Date();
            var year = date.getFullYear(),
                month = date.getMonth(),
                daysBefore = _daysBefore(date),
                daysInMonth = _daysInMonth(date),
                weeksInMonth = plugin.settings.weeksInMonth || _weeksInMonth(date, daysInMonth, daysBefore);

            if (((daysInMonth + daysBefore) / 7 ) - weeksInMonth === 0)
                weeksInMonth++;
            $tbody.empty();
            $header.html( plugin.settings.months[month] + " " + year.toString() );

            for (var weekIndex = 0,
                daysInMonthCount = 1,
                daysAfterCount = 1; weekIndex < weeksInMonth; weekIndex++ ) {

                var daysInWeekCount = 0,
                    row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($tbody);

                while ( daysBefore > 0 ) {
                    addCell(row, new Date(year, month, 1 - daysBefore), true);
                    daysBefore--;
                    daysInWeekCount++;
                }

                while ( daysInWeekCount < 7 && daysInMonthCount <= daysInMonth ) {
                    addCell(row, new Date(year, month, daysInMonthCount), false, !userChangedMonth && daysInMonthCount === date.getDate() );
                    daysInWeekCount++;
                    daysInMonthCount++;
                }

                while ( daysInMonthCount > daysInMonth && daysInWeekCount < 7 ) {
                    addCell(row, new Date(year, month, daysInMonth + daysAfterCount), true);
                    daysInWeekCount++;
                    daysAfterCount++;
                }
            }

            if(userChangedMonth)
                plugin.settings.monthItemsFormatter(eventsInMonth(date));

            $element.trigger('create');
        }

        function eventsInMonth(date){
            var events=[];
            for ( var i = 0, event, 
                begin = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                end = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), _daysInMonth(date), 23, 59, 59, 999);
                event = plugin.settings.events[i]; i++ ) {

                if ( event[plugin.settings.end] >= begin && event[plugin.settings.begin] < end ) {
                    events.push(event);
                }
            }
            events.sort(function(a, b) {
                return (a['start'] > b['start']) ? 1 : ((a['start'] < b['start']) ? -1 : 0);                    
            });
            return events;
        }

        $element.bind('change', function(event, begin) {
            var end = new Date(begin.getFullYear(), begin.getMonth(), begin.getDate() + 1, 0,0,0,0);
            var datumom = new Date(begin.getFullYear(), begin.getMonth(), begin.getDate());
            var faszom = $.format.date(datumom, plugin.settings.faszOm);
            var found = false;
            $listview.empty();
            $('<li data-role="list-divider">'+ $.format.date(begin, plugin.settings.dateFormatTitle) + '</li>').appendTo($listview);
            for ( var i = 0, event; event = plugin.settings.events[i]; i++ ) {
                if ( event[plugin.settings.end] >= begin && event[plugin.settings.begin] < end && event.statusz != 2 ) {
                    var $listItem  = $("<li class='ui-event-item'><a href='main.php?m=madatlap&munkalapid="+ event.eid +"' class='event-item-link' rel='external'><h3></h3><p></p></a></li>").appendTo($listview);
                    plugin.settings.listItemFormatter( $listItem, event );
                    found = true;
                }
                else if ( event[plugin.settings.end] >= begin && event[plugin.settings.begin] < end && event.statusz == 2 )
                {
                        var $listItem  = $("<li class='ui-event-item'><a href='main.php?m=naptartorol&munkalapid="+ event.eid +"' class='event-item-link' rel='external'><h3 style='color:red;'></h3><p style='color:red;'></p></a></li>").appendTo($listview);
                    plugin.settings.listItemFormatter( $listItem, event );
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if(!found)
                var $listItem  = $("<li class='ui-event-item'><p style='padding-top:0.65em;'><strong>Az adott napra nincs munkalap rögzítve!<br><br><a href='main.php?m=elfoglalt&datum="+faszom+"' rel='external'>Új szünnap rögzítése</a><br><br><a href='main.php?m=ugyfel' rel='external'>Új munkalap rögzítése</a></strong></p></li>").appendTo($listview);
            $listview.trigger('create').filter(".ui-listview").listview('refresh');
        });

        function listItemFormatter($listItem, event) {
            $listItem.find('h3').append(event.name);
            var startDate = $.format.date(event.start, plugin.settings.dateFormat);
            var endDate = $.format.date(event.end, plugin.settings.dateFormat);
            if(startDate == endDate) {
                $listItem.find('p').append('<strong>' + event.summary + '</strong> </p><p>');
            } else {
                $listItem.find('p').append('<strong>' + event.summary + '</strong> </p><p>');
            }
            if (event[plugin.settings.icon]) {
                $listItem.attr('data-icon', event.icon);
            }
        }

        function monthItemsFormatter(events){
            $listview.empty();
            if(events.length){
                var tr_date='';
                for ( var i = 0, event; event = events[i]; i++ ) {
                    if ( tr_date != $.format.date(event.start, "yyyyMMMMdd")) {
                        var $liDivider = $('<li data-role="list-divider">'+ $.format.date(event.start, plugin.settings.dateFormatTitle) +'</li>').appendTo($listview);
                        tr_date = $.format.date(event.start, "yyyyMMMMdd");
                    }
                    if (event.statusz != 2){
                      var $listItem  = $("<li class='ui-event-item'><a href='main.php?m=madatlap&munkalapid="+ event.eid +"' class='event-item-link' rel='external'><h3></h3><p></p></a></li>").appendTo($listview);
                    plugin.settings.listItemFormatter( $listItem, event );  
                    }
                    else if (event.statusz == 2 ) {
                      var $listItem  = $("<li class='ui-event-item'><a href='main.php?m=naptartorol&munkalapid="+ event.eid +"' class='event-item-link' rel='external'><h3 style='color:red;'></h3><p style='color:red;'></p></a></li>").appendTo($listview);
                    plugin.settings.listItemFormatter( $listItem, event );  
                    }
                }
            } else {
                var $listItem  = $("<li class='ui-event-item'><p style='padding-top:0.65em;'><strong>No scheduled events for selected month.</strong></p></li>").appendTo($listview);
            }
            $listview.trigger('create').filter(".ui-listview").listview('refresh');
        }

        $element.bind('refresh', function(event, date) {
            refresh(date);
        });
        init();
    };

    $.fn.jqmCalendar = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (!$(this).data('jqmCalendar')) {
                $(this).data('jqmCalendar', new $.jqmCalendar(this, options));
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you explain more your problem and your need plz

Comment: My calendar is delayed by 1 day from 10/29/2019. I don't understand why doing this.

Comment: The green background 2019-10-27, but the calendar event is 2019-10-28...

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Why delayed the calendar?